# Concatenation of strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation

I'm having a folder path which I need to concatenate with subfolder which is being stored in variable for ex:

I've a path `somepath\theme` now I want to add theme named in the folder something like this `somepath\theme\themeone` I've this themeone stored in variable and trying to concatenate

```
$themename = 'themeone';
$path = 'somepath\theme\' . $themename;
```

I'm getting an error unexpected end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the syntax highlighting. You're last slash is escaping the apostrophe causing your string to not terminate. As a result you are left with an open string. You need to escape that backslash.

```
$themename = 'themeone';
$path = 'somepath\\theme\\' . $themename;
```

Comment: And he should also escape the one backslash in the middle if he will use this as a path.